# Scrape prometheus metrics endpoint, convert to application insights metrics json format

Tags: solr, prometheus, azure-application-insights, solrcloud

I want to scrape an applications metrics being exposed in the prometheus format, and convert it into application insights metrics json format. (to then send onto application insights in batches).
How can I achieve this?
This is outside of an AKS cluster, otherwise I could use the Azure Monitor prometheus end point scraper. Does anything similar exist outside of AKS Azure Monitor?

More specifically in this instance looking at Solr, and using the "solr-exporter" to expose the metrics in prometheus format.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/monitoring-solr-with-prometheus-and-grafana.html

Or zookeeper JMX exporter into prometheus format.
https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/zookeeper.yaml

I don't have a prometheus server setup.

Just looking for a solution to scrape end point exposing metrics in Prometheus format, convert into the application insights metrics json format http://apmtips.com/blog/2017/10/27/send-metric-to-application-insights/
Before sending in batches.

Comment: Isn't Application Insights already able to scrape Prometheus/OpenMetrics exporters ?

Comment: From what I've read that only seems to be for applications within an AKS cluster. But yeah I'd be interested if the Java Application Insights agent, or Log Analytics agent could do this outside of an AKS cluster.